# update_post_meta attachment_image_alt description for Gutenberg

Tags: images, block-editor

I have resolve then 2016 with this solution [update_post_meta for custom field not working upon form submission](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/293072/update-post-meta-for-custom-field-not-working-upon-form-submission)
But for wordpress 5.0 with Gutenberg only in Media work, if upload the photo with block image not work. An a solution for work with "Media" and block image? Very thanks for support.